# Running code when activity closes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Hi, I need run some line of code after an activity closes but not when a new intent is started. How can I do that? I have tried `onStop()`, `onPause()` and `onDestory()` but all these also run the code when a start a new intent. I only want the code to run when the back button is pressed or the app is closed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch the back button, than add this to your activity ([API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Since API level 5 you can also use [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

If your activity is going to the background by other reasons, than onPause() should be called. You can check if the instance is killed, e.g. by the task manager, by calling [isFinishing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29). If it comes to the foreground again, onResume() is called.

Answer (score 0):

For back button, you could override `onBackPressed`.

If you want to know whether you app is being closed in `onDestroy` you could check with `this.isFinishing()` (returns a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onBackpressed() method as provided by Activity to achieve what you want.

Comment: thats great but what about when u close the app completely by going into the task manager?

Comment: Theres really nothing you can do about that. Mainly because you can't guarantee that onDestory will be called.